# Move OS to another computer

Tags: xubuntu, transfer

Is it possible to install latest Xubuntu x64 (generic kernel) to the HDD on one computer and then move this HDD to another computer? Will it break something? Is there any pitfalls i should know about?

Comment: I think you will get driver issues.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Drivers are pre-configured during the installation process and not during the boot then?

Comment: I think most standard hardware will work. I have done this on several occasions without problems.

Comment: I have done it many times without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best not to install any proprietary drivers but other wise should not be any issue as long as the PC you are moving the hard drive to is also capable of running a 64bit OS

Comment: Thanks, but do you know if device name changes will cause any mounting/booting problems?

Comment: Will cause no problems Xubuntu will seamlessly adapt to it's new environment, it is something I have done a few times without issue.